# What is -b switch in memcached

Tags: memcached

memcached.exe -h

> -b run a managed instanced (mnemonic: buckets)

what the heck does this mean? Googling did not help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code, this appears to mean that the memcached has multiple independent buckets.

This is probably for security or accounting reasons, allowing you to have multiple concurrent users of a memcached, without one user getting the results that a different one cached.

http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/webstack/memcached-incubator/branches/performance/server/memcached.h#51

Comment: You are right, it's not very clear, but it is the source, and thus definitive.